# Avoiding string literals when using ModelState.AddModelError

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC 5 app when I want to return validation error for the form values I use this pattern in the Controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PropertyName", "Validation Message");
```

Is there a recommended practice that does not use string literal in the Controller for property name?

I am using .Net 4.5 and I would rather not upgrade to .Net 4.6.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 and would rather not upgrade to Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

C# 6 introduces the [nameof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator, so you can do the following:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(this.PropertyName), "Validation Message");
```

This requires Visual Studio 2015 though.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response RB. However I am using .net 4.5 and I would rather not upgrade to .net 4.6. I updated the question to include this information.

Comment: It is a C# 6 compiler feature, not a .NET 4.6 feature. You can run code using the nameof operator on .NET 4.0 onwards (I'm pretty sure you could target any version of the framework, but I happen to have tested .NET 4.0...!)

Comment: Thanks again. I am also using Visual Studio 2013 and would rather not upgrade to Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be achieved like this:

1) Define a base controller that inherits `Controller`:

```
class BaseController<TCtr> : Controller
```

2) Have your actual control inherit `BaseController` instead of `Controller`:

```
class YourController : BaseController<TCtr>
```

3) Define the following function in your `BaseController`:

```
protected virtual void AddModelError<TProp>(Expression<Func<TCtr, TProp>> expression, String message)
    {
        var prop = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        ModelState.AddModelError(prop.Member.Name, message);
    }
```

This allows you to write something like this in your controller:

```
AddModelError(ctrl => SomeProperty, "Validation failed");
```